# memory error in c program

Tags: c, linux, gcc

I have made a program in which I am handling files but I am getting this error
(I have run it through `gdb`)

> Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
>   0x0016e50b in vfprintf () from /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6

I am not getting the exact line that contain error.

Can anybody tell me

- what this error means
- does it occur for any special reason
- or is it general error occurring because of many reason?

Comment: Got some code? what happens when you debug it

Comment: hard to tell unless you show the code

Comment: in gdb, type `bt` to get a backtrace. you'll have more information about where your code is failing. Post the backtrace as well as the relevant parts of your code.

Comment: It is possible that your program is trying to access forbidden memory locations. Check for memory leaks in whatever arrays or pointers you have. Also, provide code so we can look into it.

Answer (score 4):

> What does this error mean?

It basically means that you're accessing memory that you're not supposed to be accessing.

> Does it occur for any special reason?

A segmentation violation can occur for a huge number of reasons. However, since it's happening in `vfprintf`, it's likely to be limited to something like:

- Invalid file pointer.
- Not passing enough parameters for the format string.
- Passing a NULL pointer for a C string.
- Passing a non-null-terminated pointer for a C string.
- Memory corruption from a totally different part of the program.

That's the most likely reasons.

> Or is it a general error occurring because of many reasons?

As I said, it *can* occur for a vast number of reasons but it's probavly limited based on your circumstances.

Check all of the parameters before calling the `printf` call (not with `printf` of course, use some more robust debugging code such as printing each character of a string with flushing and fsyncing after each). And check that the file handle is valid and that the number of parameters passed to `vprintf` matches those specified in the format string.

Comment: Use valgrind to determine the actual problem including the code lines affected (if debugging information is present in the binary).